# iFrame ignores width attribute

Tags: iphone, web-applications, iframe, width

I check the User Agent with JavaScript and depending on which i want to change the width of the iframe. The iframe is loaded, but on the iPhone the width attribute is ignored.

I have experimented with different widths and while loading you can be seen that the iframe has for a very short time the right size, but then it goes about a width of 1000px or higher.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--

        if (iPhone == 1) {
            document.write('<iframe width=\"962px\" height=\"800px\" style=\"position: absolute; left:0px; top:69px;\" src=\"http://xxxxxxx/index.aspx?app=0&iPhone=' + iPhone + '&iPad=' + iPad + '\"/>');
        }
        else {
            document.write('<iframe class=\"eMeeting\" src="http://xxxxx/index.aspx?app=0&iPhone=' + iPhone + '&iPad=' + iPad + '\"/>');
        }


//-->
</script>
```

EDIT:

the userAgent Code

```
if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {

iPhone = 1;
```

}

Comment: Are you sure your UA detection code works? there's none posted here..

Comment: Thought the same und so I have set the variable simply to 1, but the problem still exists.